# Recreating a dataframe (with missing dates 're-inserted'); how to make index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

From a dataframe `df1`, I'm trying to create a new dataframe `df2` that also contains values for the missing dates (eg, Saturdays, Sundays, which will get Friday's values) in `df1`. The below seems to work, except that my new `df2` doesn't seem to have the same type of index (as `df1`: `DATE`). How can I make sure that `df2` is also indexed by dates?

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime as dt
df1 = web.get_data_fred(['EUR1MTD156N'], start = dt.date(2000, 1, 4))
df1
def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + dt.timedelta(n)
start_date = df1.first_valid_index()
end_date = df1.last_valid_index()
dlist2 = []
for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date + dt.timedelta(1)):
    try:
        last_value = df1['EUR1MTD156N'][single_date]
     except:
        pass
     dlist2.append(last_value)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dlist2, columns = ['EUR1MTD156N'])
df2
```

BTW: If there is a more simple/efficient way to do this, then I am all ears...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make a new index with pd.date_range and then reindex and fill forward.

```
df1 = df1.dropna().sort_index()
start_date = df1.index.min()
end_date = df1.index.max()

idx = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')
df2 = df1.reindex(idx)
df2['EUR1MTD156N'] = df2['EUR1MTD156N'].ffill()
```